# How do I configure Office to talk to my SharePoint server?

Tags: office

I just want to start by saying I have no idea about anything SharePoint related, so plan on working my way through and asking questions when I get stuck

We have a 3rd Party Hosted Exchange 2010 / SharePoint 2010 service by Intermedia.

I have around 50 users who are connected to Exchange and I have created a SharePoint. I can browse to and upload documents to this SharePoint via a web interface. This seems quite limited by the mere fact I can only upload one file at a time.

I want to understand how I connect my users to this SharePoint via Office. There seems to be the ability for Office to save to a SharePoint etc, but I can't work out how.

I wish to use SharePoint as a Document Management system and control permissions / revisions of documents etc and allow people to work from office rather than a web interface if possible.

All comments, suggestions, reading materials, links are welcomed. This is day one, im sure once I get a better understanding of how it all works it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between Office and SharePoint started way back from Microsoft Office 2000 and Windows SharePoint Services. It has been improving from then on, and has reached an exceptional integration between each other with lots of features to talk about today.

In order to achieve the best user experience with Microsoft Office and SharePoint integration, its recommended to have Office Professional Plus 2010 and SharePoint Server 2010. Here is [an article from MSDN](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2010/02/24/sharepoint-and-office-integration.aspx) that details the features that were available at the times of SharePoint 2007 and has an update of 2010 as well. This article and whitepapers included will give you an idea about the features that have been evolving through these years.

Some of the collaboration features like,

1. Calander Overlays
2. Integrating Contacts
3. Alerts, RSS subscriptions, etc
4. Social Connectors, Workspaces, etc

are detailed in a blog post - http://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/outlook-2010-sharepoint-2010-integration/

There are also e-books available explaining these collaboration features - http://books.google.co.in/books?id=e3tHRnP7PmIC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

So you will have a lot of reading to do... :)

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

MS Office has integration features built in that allow users to initiate actions from either their local Office client or from within the SharePoint environment.  We would be looking at things like Check-In/Check-Out, Opening, and Saving documents.  Editing document properties and meta-data is also available.

The Office site has some great how to instructions such as these:

- Save a document to SharePoint - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-a-document-to-sharepoint-from-office-2010-HA010380214.aspx
- Open or check out a document from SharePoint - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/open-or-check-out-office-files-from-a-sharepoint-library-HA101848056.aspx